# php include virtual path

Tags: php, apache, path, include

In my live site I have php include() and require() that have full path such as:
/www/mysite.com/webapps/mmh/head.php or /www/mysite.com/webapps/ROOT/zip/BoundaryWizard.php

Now, I want to do some local development on my windows machine (Xampp), so obviously none of those path work.

Is there a way to tweak the apache or php settings to dynamically translate say /www/mysite.com/webapps/mmh/ to c:\xamp\mysite\some_other_arbitrary_folder ?

I assume the best way would be to have used relative paths is the first place, but this is legacy code, could take a while to fix ...

Comment: Not an answer, but in the future consider defining a ROOT_PATH constant to avoid these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define() your application path and then use find and replace in a text editor, most editors have that feature.

Comment: This means the code running in the development environment can't run unmodified in production, or test etc., environment. Better keep your code working in each environment and use a single configuration file to put these settings, plus things like database connection parameters etc.

Answer (score 2):

The right answer here (sorry) is that you should fix it. Have a common file where you declare a variable/contanst which is used to specify the path.

C'mon, it's not *that* hard. `sed` or any semi-good IDE will make changing a string on a bunch of files an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your code then create those directories.

You're in trouble if you ever have to switch hosts, so I'd recommend changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think that a search/replace wouldn't hurt too much in this case, as it's not difficult.

The other thing you could do is to move your DocumentRoot so that it's at C:\www\mysite.com...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the best solution but for a not so clever solution
you can use a simlink (I don't know how it is called in windows systems, maybe just links?).